# Correctly adding defer attribute to script tag with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, setattribute, script-tag, deferred-loading

I am trying to add a deferred script tag like this:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('src', '/script.js');
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  script.setAttribute('defer', true);//this is the code in question!
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
```

But I found out the result script tag will generate the `defer` attribute like `defer=true` instead of just `defer`.

Are they same? What is the implication if I do `defer=true` rather than `defer`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would change it to:

```
script.setAttribute("defer", "defer");
```

They usually behave the same (although the docs technically state the value of an attribute such as defer should not be "true" or false") - or at least in any browser I've used boolean attributes in. The attribute `defer` is usually implemented to take effect *if present* in the script tag. Its value is ignored.

**That being said**, the spec specifies that a boolean attribute's value should not be present, or otherwise should be set to itself, with no leading / trailing whitespace (case does not matter). So, it's preferable to leave the value as the name of the attribute when setting it dynamically.

Refer to this documentation for boolean attributes (HTML5): https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute

Quote from that doc:

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
>   absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> > **Note:** The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes.
> >     To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted
> >     altogether.

And this documentation for the defer attribute (HTML5):
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-defer

It states:

> The async and defer attributes are boolean attributes that indicate how > the script should be executed.

**Update:** It looks like if you set an attribute to the empty string, it will add the attribute with no value. This is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: (chrome 94)

`script.defer = true;`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a script tag and want to add defer/async attribute. Then use this code.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    var fbChatScript = document.querySelector('#facebook-jssdk');
    fbChatScript.setAttribute('defer', '');
});
```